# The are the differences between Scanf() and Scanln()?

Tags: go

please look at the code below:

1. The First

- code

```
    for {
            fmt.Println("--------start--------")
            fmt.Println("please input j:")
            var j int
            fmt.Scanf("%v", &j)
            fmt.Println("your intput j:", j)
            fmt.Println("--------end--------\n")
        }
```

- resut

```
D:\project\go-workspace\src\go_code\chapter10>go run demo07/test.go
--------start--------
please input j:
1
your intput j: 1
--------end--------

--------start--------
please input j:
your intput j: 0
--------end--------

--------start--------
please input j:
```

2. The Second

```
    for {
        fmt.Println("--------start--------")
        fmt.Println("please input j: ")
        var j int
        fmt.Scanln(&j)
        fmt.Println("your intput j:", j)
        fmt.Println("--------end--------\n")
    }
```

- result

```
D:\project\go-workspace\src\go_code\chapter10>go run demo07/test.go
--------start--------
please input j:
1<p>
your intput j: 1
--------end--------

--------start--------
please input j:
```

I don't know why this is happening,

and I want know more details between the Scanf() and Scanln()!

Hope someone can help me, thanks~

Comment: Did you [read the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)?

Comment: You should check the error returned by the functions too; they are trying to tell you when the input couldn't be decoded as you request.

Comment: @KyleLemons Yeah, but I don't know why j=0 is automatically executed, I'm sure I only hit enter once

Comment: Because your scanf doesn't consume the newline.  You want "%d\n" if you want to consume the newline too.  Otherwise the next scanf will find a newline not a number.  The error message probably shows this.

Answer (score 1):

The differences of these two functions are in the expectations they have towards the standard input.

- `Scanf` expects your input to match the provided format string, which can have an arbitrary layout. Format specifiers (or 'verbs') must match the number of given arguments.
- `Scanln` expects your input to be determined by a newline signal. Additionally the number of separated strings should match the number of provided arguments.

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) is very clear on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand why j=0 is automatically executed in the first code.

Comment: @BGnv5 `0` is the zero value (or default) of int-typed variables, which `j` is. So if you enter a new line without a previous value, it prints 0. From my testing, it doesn't print it automatically. You must have entered a new line twice.

Comment: @BGnv5 See more about [Zero Values here](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12).

Comment: The fact that I only hit enter once, that's what confused me.You can copy the following code and run it in your editor.

Comment: @BGnv5 but can you then up vote and mark your question answered? Thanks

Comment: I sincerely want to vote for your answer, but the system prompt :"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded"